# How to integrate form in Dialogflow CX?

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I want to create a delivery service bot. So, in one step I need to collect multiple data from user, like - user email, phone number, package weight, height etc. Now using slot-filling is cumbersome. Because , user may get frustrated answering the questions one by one when they can fillup a form instead.

Now, is it possible to integrate form in dialogflow cx? I have been looking for it for weeks.
I even tried to integrate using webhook .
Thank you.

I searched for google form integration with dialogflow cx but I did not find any. There is no custom payload to get user input by form as to my knowledge.
I even tried to integrate form using webhook. I wrote a simple form code and then deployed it using flask and ngrok, Then, I used that webhook.
But the custom payload is not showing in dialogflow messenger. However, I can see the response in json format.

Comment: what messaging integration do you want to use? is the integration (Slack, Whatsapp, Messenger etc) that need to allow in this case the form, not dialogflow.